# Trouble with Powershell script to call HTTP POST with multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, powershell, multipartform-data

I am developing a powershell script that should invoke a REST API using the HTTP POST method. The REST API is used to restore an application specific backup resource from external backup file. the KeyName for backup file in the form data must be "backupFile".
The content type is multipart/form-data. Here is what i am doing:

```
function invoke-rest {
param([string]$uri)
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
#$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Credentials = New-Object system.net.networkcredential("user","password")
$request.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = $true;
$boundary = "--------------"+(get-date -format yyyymmddhhmmss).ToString()
$header = "--"+$boundary
$body = $header + "`r`n" +"Content-Disposition: form-data; name='backupFile'; filename='somefile.sql.gz'"+"`r`n" + "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"+"`r`n`r`n"

$body = $body + [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($(Get-Content 'somefile.sql.gz' -Encoding byte)) + "`r`n"
$footer = $header+"--"
$body = $body + $footer

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)
$request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary="+$boundary
$request.Method = "Post"
$request.keepAlive = $true
$request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length

$requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.Write($bytes,0,$bytes.length);
$requestStream.Flush();
$requestStream.Close();

$response = $request.GetResponse()
$responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $responseStream
$xmlDump = $stream.ReadToEnd()
$output = [xml]$xmlDump
$response.close()
return $output
}
$uri = "http://localhost/rest/backups"
invoke-rest $uri
```

The error being thrown: **REST request failed, A data form must exist with the name backupFile, returning: Bad Request (400)**

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but unless this code must run on PowerShell 2.0, you should consider using `Invoke-RestMethod`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx

Comment: This sort of thing is hard to help with.  My general advice is to grab Fiddler from http://www.telerik.com/fiddler (it's free) and use it to observe differences between your script and something that works (curl, interactive form submission, etc).  Knowing what is different between a successful request and a failed one is usually enough to get you over the hump.

Comment: briantist, this has to be in powershell 2.0 unfortunately.

Comment: keith hill, I narrowed it down now. The problem is either in encoding the sql.gz file or in the way i am providing the content-type or content-encoding headers. The content-type for the 'request body' is supposed to be either application/x-gzip or application/octet-stream and for the 'request header' it is supposed to be 'multipart/form-data'. Do you think anything is wrong in the way i am specifying content-type or in the way i am encoding it? The content type looks fine when i compare it with fiddler's request body. But not sure how i can figure out the encoding part!

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, the 400 probably means something was incorrect in generating the

Is the file the only parameter you need to submit on the request?  If so, you may be able to use the WebClient.UploadFile API and let it handle generating the bulk of the request.

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials = $creds
$client.UploadFile('http://localhost/rest/backups', 'c:\temp\somefile.sql.gz')
```

If you do need to submit multiple parameters in a mime multipart request, then you're looking at a world of pain.  I've had to do this through powershell myself and it's not fun at all, particularly when you start involving binary data. After much frustration & headbanging, I ended up with the following to convert a hashtable of values and outputs a multipart.  Sorry I can't spot exactly what's wrong with your code, but perhaps this can will either work outright for you, or lead you to identify what your issue is.

```
function ConvertTo-MimeMultiPartBody
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Boundary,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [hashtable]$Data
    )

    $body = '';

    $Data.GetEnumerator() |% {
        $name = $_.Key
        $value = $_.Value

        $body += "--$Boundary`r`n"
        $body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"$name`""
        if ($value -is [byte[]]) {
            $fileName = $Data['FileName']
            if(!$fileName) {
                $fileName = $name
            }
            $body += "; filename=`"$fileName`"`r`n"
            $body += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
            #ISO-8859-1 is only encoding where byte value == code point value
            $value = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString($value)
        }
        $body += "`r`n`r`n"
        $body += $value
        $body += "`r`n"
    }
    $body += "--$boundary--"
    return $body
}
```